# Run node app in Travis

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

I currently build a server side app with node js. 
To test it, I use Travis, which [runs npm test by default](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs#Default-Test-Script).

Now I want also to test if the dependencies are correct and therefore start the app within Travis with

```
nodejs app.js
```

How can I run this task in Travis?

Comment: Travis like a lot of CI similar services are supposed to assume or imply your setup and run tests and pre/after build tasks automatically.

Please consider this is not actually an appropiate question at Stackoverflow, make sure to read the docs or any official guides for Travis.

Answer (score 10):

You can run any task like you would expect it to be on a unix shell:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "5"
before_script:
  - npm install
script:
  - node app.js
  - npm test
```

However your purpose is covered already by the `npm install` command. If this fails and also subsequently your `npm test` fails, the build will not succeed.

For more complicated examples, where you need to run actual servers, say in API end-2-end testing I would use `docker-compose` instead. But this is way too much here.

> travis.yml

```
language: node_js
sudo: required
services:
  - docker
cache:
   directories:
     - node_modules
node_js:
  - 5
before_install:
  - npm install -g node-gyp
before_script:
  - npm install
  - npm install -g standard
  - docker-compose build
  - docker-compose up -d
  - sleep 3
script:
  - npm test
after_script:
  - docker-compose kill
```

> docker-compose.yml

```
api1:
  build: .
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
  ports:
    - 3955
  links:
    - mongo
    - redis
  environment:
    - REDIS_HOST=redis
    - MONGO_HOST=mongo
    - IS_TEST=true
  command: "node app.js"

api2:
  build: .
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
  ports:
    - 3955
  links:
    - mongo
    - redis
  environment:
    - REDIS_HOST=redis
    - MONGO_HOST=mongo
    - IS_TEST=true
  command: "node app.js"

mongo:
  image: mongo
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
  command: "--smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null"

redis:
   image: redis
   ports:
     - "6379:6379"

haproxy:
  image: haproxy:1.5
  volumes:
     - ./cluster:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/
  links:
    - "api1"
    - "api2"
  ports:
    - 80:80
    - 70:70
  expose:
    - "80"
    - "70"
```

Answer (score 9):

The original simple answer is close, but I needed one modification found on this forum: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1321

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "6"
before_script:
  - npm install
script:
  - node app.js &
  - npm test
```

I needed the ampersand (&) at the end of the `node app.js` to start my server process in the background. Otherwise, it runs the server in the foreground, waits, and never gets to the `npm test`.